# Why is my MySQL prepared statement not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to convert a MySQL query to a prepared statement and having trouble, for some reason I am not getting any results. The MySQL query definitely works but I just can't see what I am doing wrong. I'd really appreciate any help.
In my error log I get the error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

```
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT up.id,up.file,up.title,p.user_name,p.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cp.user_id,'~',cp.user_name) SEPARATOR '|') AS tagGroup
    FROM tbl_uploads up
    LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file
    LEFT JOIN tbl_users cp ON cp.user_id = c.collab_userid
    GROUP BY up.file ORDER BY up.id DESC");

$results->execute(); //Execute prepared Query

$results->bind_result($page_id,$user_id,$file); //bind variables to prepared statement

//output results from database

while($results->fetch()){ //fetch values

    $page_id = explode (",", $row['id'] );
    $user_id = explode (",", $row['user_id'] );
    $files = explode (",", $row['file']);

    foreach($user_id as $user_id) {
        foreach($files as $file) {
            foreach($page_id as $page_id) {
                echo '<li>'.$page_id.' - '. $user_id.' - '.$file.'</li>';    
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: first of all you need to fix this
`foreach($file as $file) {`

to this:
`foreach($files as $file) {`

Comment: Thanks. I corrected that but no variables get echoed out, only the hyphens between each variable. My error console says` Undefined variable: row`.

Comment: Same for the `$user_id` and `$page_id`!

Comment: Well, yes… where *do* you define `$row`…? (Hint: you don't.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code accordingly:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT up.id,up.file,up.title,p.user_name,p.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cp.user_id,'~',cp.user_name) SEPARATOR '|') AS tagGroup
    FROM tbl_uploads up
    LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file
    LEFT JOIN tbl_users cp ON cp.user_id = c.collab_userid
    GROUP BY up.file ORDER BY up.id DESC");

$stmt->bind_param( 'iis', $page_id, $user_id, $file );

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

//output results from database

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){

    $page_ids = explode( ",", $row['id'] );
    $user_ids = explode( ",", $row['user_id'] );
    $files = explode( ",", $row['file'] );

    foreach( $user_ids as $user_id ) {
        foreach( $files as $file ) {
            foreach( $page_ids as $page_id ) {


                echo '<li>'.$page_id.' - '. $user_id.' - '.$file.'</li>';

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at the [example](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#107568). Also [`bind_param` method](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

And one more thing: Storing `page_ids`, `user_ids`, `files` in one field in the database separating with commas is not the best db structure!

**Update:**
In case you are not passing any parameters to SQL statement, use the following:

```
$query = "SELECT up.id,up.file,up.title,p.user_name,p.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cp.user_id,'~',cp.user_name) SEPARATOR '|') AS tagGroup
    FROM tbl_uploads up
    LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file
    LEFT JOIN tbl_users cp ON cp.user_id = c.collab_userid
    GROUP BY up.file ORDER BY up.id DESC";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $page_ids = explode (",", $row['id'] );
        $user_ids = explode (",", $row['user_id'] );
        $files = explode (",", $row['file']);

        foreach($user_ids as $user_id) {
            foreach($files as $file) {
                foreach($page_ids as $page_id) {


                    echo '<li>'.$page_id.' - '. $user_id.' - '.$file.'</li>';

                }
            }
        }
    }

    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still getting these two errors: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in AND Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Comment: Well, you are not passing any parameters to SQL statement. Either pass them or rewrite your code without `bind_param`.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. It works great  and I now have a better understanding.